# Super slow admin panel

Tags: admin, wp-admin

My admin panel in wordpress is super slow. I disabled all the plugins, I changed the theme to "Twenty Eleven" and I updated Wordpress. Still, the admin panel is very slow. I have 2008 posts and 6 pages.

My front end though is not slow, even though I disabled cache.

Does anybody have an idea of what can I do about that?! Thank you very much!

Comment: Try optimizing the database, there are plugins that do that. Make sure you make a backup before though. Also, you can watch the browser's status bar while page is loading to see if the admin panel is having issues connecting to any outside links.

Comment: Done. Deleted about 13000 post revisions... but still slow

Comment: What is "slow"? Please also open your developer tools and take a look if some request 404s or some CDN doesn't respond and blocks page loading.

Comment: It takes 8.5 seconds to load the posts page. I checked the console and everything is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Set the install to default, all plugins inactive and the default theme. After this step will not reduce the load, analyze the install, like with the plugin "Debug Objects", view the queries tab, there will give you information about slow DB Queries.

Comment: I have a bunch of queries running, some of the slow ones are from the Wordpress core

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason this happens is--plugins that add functionality to the Dashboard, especially columns in post/page info. Try deactivating any plugins that do that, and see what happens. Reactivate them one by one to see if it's a cumulative effect, or a specific plugin.

Comment: Hi. All my plugins are deactivated and it's still slow.

Comment: Network and database are "slow" in general, WP does a lot of both (looking up posts, fetching plugin update list etc.)